# Changing bash colors is causing pasted text in terminal to stay on screen

Tags: command-line, bash, terminal

Default PS1 looks like this: `PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$ '`. Everything works fine no matter what text I paste in my terminal. But if I try to change colors, for example: `PS1='\e[0;31m[\u@\h \W]\$ \e[m '` (I'm going to use this command as example to paste in terminal) (my current PS1 is `PS1='\e[0;31m\w \e[m`')
and now try to paste it, it's going to look like this:

[image]

Text is always selected, i can't erase it (tried both Backspace and Ctrl+W), the only way to get rid of it on the current line is to go on another one (press Enter).

Comment: This prompt seems wrong - `\e[m` doesn't seem to be [supported](https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting). You might have wanted to terminate it with `\e[0m`?

Comment: Tried it, result is still the same.

Comment: @harrymc: An empty or unspecified parameter is equivalent to 0 for `\e[ ... m` (it's either 0 or 1 for various other `\e[ ...` sequences). Only very few (less popular) terminal emulators don't recognize the empty variant, or sometimes they recognize `\e[m` alone but not intermixed `\e[;1m` (which is normally equivalent to `\e[0;1m`), but those in general are just rare bugs.

Comment: Thanks for linking the duplicates, I wrapped everything with "\[" & "\]" and it worked.